# SQL Left join based on existing value

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

Attempting to make sub menu filter based on relations in MySQL DB.

Main Groups: Drink, Food, Deli, Shelf
Sub Groups: Coffee, Tea, Crisps, Asas

When using my `LEFT JOIN` query i am getting `asas` button appear multiple times.

Clearly i am not executing this in the correct way, what would be the ideal method to achieve the desired result.

Essentially the desired result would be when you click `Drink` button the sub nav filters and shows only drinks. This entire project is pre-loaded with ajax and rests heavily on ajax and classes.

The clear issue here currently is that there are multiple times the button `asas` appears... not the desired result.

[image: Blue=Main Menu / Purple= Sub Menu]

**The MySQL**

```
$sql7x = " SELECT * FROM items_sub_section_list 
                LEFT JOIN item_groups ig ON (items_sub_section_list.item_sub_sec_id=ig.item_sub_sec_id)
                WHERE items_sub_section_list.item_sub_sec_id>0
                ORDER BY items_sub_section_list.item_sub_sec_id ASC ";
```

The Tables i have in the MySQL DB are:

`items_section_list: 'sec_id' , 'title'`

`items_sub_section_list: 'item_sub_sec_id' , 'title'`

`item_groups: 'item_id' , 'section_id' , 'item_sub_sec_id'`

I feel there may be a much better way to achieve the desired result. Perhaps a MySQL query based on a for each where perhaps? I am a little stumped to say the least on this.

Comment: Is the selection list the items a customer picks from the list or is it a grouping of the individual items. Like Hot drinks or cold drinks?

Comment: This is not customer based, its for epos system. The `section list` is just the main group of categories. The `sub section list` is a group of categories that can be under the main categories. Such as, coffee as an item can be referenced to a sub group of any title, but will always be a component of the drinks category.

Comment: Ah. Then the sub selection list will always be available too. IE, there will always be a selection list item for a sub selection list item. That means right below 'FROM item_groups ig' you would want to add a join on the sub selection group to get those titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the parent id is in the sub-section table and the sub-section id is in the individual item table. I am also assuming a section only has one parent group and individual items are only in one sub-section.

```
SELECT ig.section_id, ig.select_textName,
  isl.sec_id, isl.sec_textName,
  issl.item_sub_sec_id, issl.individualItemName
FROM item_groups ig  
JOIN ON items_section_list isl (ig.section_id = isl.section_id)
LEFT JOIN ON items_sub_section_list issl (isl.sec_id = issl.sec_id)
            WHERE issl.item_sub_sec_id>0
            ORDER BY ig.select_textName, isl.sec_textName, issl.individualitemName,   
            issl.item_sub_sec_id ASC
```